# Force links in lotus notes emails to always open in a new window?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, email, internet-explorer-8, lotus-notes

I'm using C# to generate emails that are read using Lotus notes. The problem is we want the links to always open up in a new window in IE but they always open in the same window when I use "Lotus Notes - Basic Edition" (8.0.1) but when I use the regular lotus notes 8.0.1, they always open up in a new window. I tried looking around in the preferences but can't find a setting that'll explain this.

(note: I'm using IE 8 as my default browser. If I change it to chrome or FF this doesn't happen)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you are still facing this problem or not, but for the sake of other users posting the solutions.

In Location Preferences, under Internet Browser, don't select "Microsoft Internet Explorer", instead select others and then browse to path of Internet Explorer - 
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE"

Save it. Now your links will always open in different IE window.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the emails, are you able to enter HTML code for the links?  If so, perhaps you just need to add a target="_blank" attribute?

The preferences for which browser to use in Lotus Notes are set on the client's location document, so I'm not sure if that's part of the issue your having?

Comment: Yep I tried target='_blank' but that didn't help. The three main suspects here are the html,the browser or lotus notes. It's not html since the same html opens a new window in regular lotus and it could be partially IE 8 since this is not a problem if I set the default browser for my system to chrome(and tell lotus notes to use the default browser on the system). I would say it's not the browser too since this doesn't happen when using the regular lotus notes client. Therefore the last suspect left here is "Lotus Notes".

Comment: Your reasoning makes sense and it doesn't surprise me that Notes might have an odd behavior like this.  I haven't tried using Lotus Notes Basic Edition, but I've encountered plenty of odd Notes bugs in my time.

I wonder if the client supports javascript?  Perhaps if Notes is just ignoring the target attribute, you could add a link with an href of "javascript:void(window.open('mywindow.html'))".  If supported, that should get Notes to open in a new window.

Comment: tried the javascript just now. That pops up an alert saying "Javascript is only supported within a document"

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an admin question, but the link will get opened based on the preferences in the individual client.  In 8 basic the location document controls this.  Edit the current location document and go to the Internet Browser tab.  You can then choose which browser to use. It sounds like you have it set to use IE inside notes, rather than separately.

Comment: Yep, you're right it's an admin question. I've contacted them but they can't seem to figure it out. We've looked at the location documents too. We can't use the IE inside notes since our web app has had some unique problems there and we encourage people to use regular IE or FF/chrome. Also so far we've concluded that this problem only happens in notes basic and not regular notes.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  Did editing your location document fix the problem?  Notes 8 Standard uses a different preferences setting to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you can open links properly with Firefox, Chrome means the issue is not with Lotus Notes.

I have seen issues where IE wasn't working with _Blank. Switching off UAE resolved the issue.